# bundle identifiers iOS

Tags: ios

How do I find out the bundle identifiers for the app I'm creating... I have the APIs from Google Maps, but I need to find out what my bundle identifiers are.

Comment: You need to specify the bundle identifier, usually reverse domain with app name. It's your decision, what should be the value for that field.

Answer (score 1):

Just select your target in Xcode, go to the General tab, and there you find the bundle identifier (see picture).

[image]

The bundle identifier is just a unique identifier that you can choose freely (provided it is not already taken -- by using the reverse domain notation to define it you can reduce the probability it is).

Answer (score 0):

Check your application plist file, that will contain an entry for Bundle Identifier. Some thing like this ->

[image: Bundle Identifier]